# Member's of a college club! Counting!

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Five college clubs each have $100$ members. Each pair of the clubs contains exactly $10$ members. Each intersection of three clubs contains $3$ members. Strict college rules prevent anyone from belonging to $4$ clubs at once. How many people are in the five clubs?

Is inclusion-exclusion method used for this problem? My attempt is:
$$500=100+100+100+100+100 - 10-10-10-10-10 + 3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3 - X$$
$X$ represents the people who are in five clubs? Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want inclusion-exclusion, but you start with the $5 \times 100$ members.  Then how many pairs of clubs are there?  You have double counted the $10$ in each pair, so take them out.  Now the people in three clubs were counted three times in the first, then removed three times in the second, so put them back in.  How many sets of three clubs are there?

Answer (score 0):

In one club, denote $A$, there are 100 member. You can use the inclusion-exclusion method or you can separate the members:

"The members who have four or five memberships"$=0$ , because of the "strict rules"

"The members in $A$ who have three memberships"$=3*$"number of intersections of three clubs containing $A$"

$$3*\binom42=18$$

"The members in $A$ who have precisely two membership"$=10*$"number of pairs containing $A$"$-$"members in three clubs":

$$10*\binom41-18=22$$

"The members who only have one membership in one club"$=100-$"members in two clubs"$-$"members in three clubs":

$$100-22-18=60$$

Now you can sum this up:

There are five clubs. Members with only one membership: $5*60=300$

Members with exactly two membership: $\frac12*\binom52*22=110$ , because you count each member two times

Members with exactly three membership: $\frac13*\binom53*18=60$ , because you count each member three times

The total sum: $300+110+60=470$